# undefined method after using includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'll start how my models looks:

```
User -> has_one :customer, has_one :employee, has_many :appointments
Customer -> belongs_to :user
Employee -> belongs_to :user
Appointment -> belongs_to :user
```

And now in view:

```
<% @appointments.order(:appointment_date).each do |appointment| %>
            <% if appointment.confirmation == wait_or_confirmed?(@status) %>
              <tr>
                <td><%= appointment.purpose %></td>
                <td><%= appointment.appointment_date %></td>
                <td><%= appointment.appointment_time %></td>
                <td><%= Employee.find(appointment.employee_id).first_name %>  <%= Employee.find(appointment.employee_id).last_name %></td>
                <td><%= Customer.find(appointment.customer_id).first_name %>  <%= Customer.find(appointment.customer_id).last_name %></td>
                <td><%= link_to 'Show', appointment_path(appointment), class: "btn btn-primary" %></td>
              </tr>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
```

My brother told me i shouldnt pick up informtaions from database in views so i tried using includes:

```
@appointments = Appointment.all
@users = User.includes(:appointments)
```

And after combination in view it still doesn't work. Can someone help me?

Comment: what method is undefined? Also your brother is correct and these lines `Employee.find(appointment.employee_id).first_name`, `Customer.find(appointment.customer_id).first_name`, etc. are violating that suggestion. Furthermore `Appointment` does not seem to belong to an `Employee` and yet you are querying it as if it does?

Comment: I don't really understand your User/Employee/Customer data model... Shouldn't it be `Appointment belongs_to :employee; belongs_to :customer` and `Employee has_many :appointments` and `Customer has_many :appointments`? I don't see a need for the `User` model, at least with regard to these associations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
Employee.find(appointment.employee_id).first_name
```

Do this:

```
appointment.employee.first_name
```

For *performance*, in the controller, you can also replace this:

```
@appointments = Appointment.all
```

With this:

```
@appointments = Appointment.all.includes(:employee, :customer)
```

By doing so, you are eager-loading all associated employee and customer data from the database in a *single* query, rather than one at a time.

Comment: thank you very much for this! It worked but i had to add belongs_to and has_many statements to customer and employee model as you wrote in comment to my question. Again thanks!